# how to make an InnerHTML fadeOut

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the user clicks on a button it appears some text with innerHTML, and already have added fadeIn and fadeOut, but what I´am trying to do is when the user clicks outside the button the text disappear, I already achieve the disappearing text but how to I add the fadeOut to it.

I tried by changing the fadeIn and fadeOut.

JS

```
function some() {
  var textElement = document.getElementById("text1");
  textElement.className = "fadeIn2";
  textElement.innerHTML = "";
  textElement.focus();
  textElement.className = "fadeOut2";
}

window.addEventListener("click", function(e){   
  if (document.getElementById("1").contains(e.target)){
    // Clicked in box
    console.log("Foo");
  } else {
    some(); //function some is called
    console.log("Bar");
  }
});
```

CSS

```
.fadeIn2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fadeOut2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 1.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 1.5s;
  -o-transition: all 1.5s;
}
```

HTML

```
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Why was this question down voted? He tried his code, it didn't work and he asked, and he gets downvoted. Why?

Comment: Possibly the expletives used in the console.logs?

Comment: @Gosi it might have been downvoted because of the explicit wording that the original author used before it was moderated.

Comment: Yes the next time, I will set better expletives guys, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me other than a portion of the event listener. You check to see if an element contains e.target, when you should actually check to see if the element is equal to e.target:

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(e){   
  if (e.target === document.getElementById("1")) {
    console.log("clicked in box");
  } else {
    some();
    console.log("didn't click in box");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description sounds like you are trying to achieve an info window that can be toggled by clicks.

```js
var infoWindow = document.getElementById('info');

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var isButton = false;
  e.path.splice(0, e.path.length - 3).forEach(function (each) {
    if (each.id === 'show') {
      isButton = true;
    }
  });
  
  if (isButton) {
    infoWindow.classList.add('show');
  } else {
    infoWindow.classList.remove('show');
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#info {
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: visibility .3s, opacity .3s;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#info.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity .3s;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="info">
  Some text here.
</div>
<button id="show">Show Info</button>
```